# Processing file with occurs clause

Tags: cobol

I'm trying to read a sequential file and write it to other file (with a different structure) using a COBOL program.

The structure of the old file contains a field that includes a table (an array).

So instead of using "move field-old to field-new" I need to write a loop for this table.
How do I do that?

Comment: You do realise there was a point in my posting an answer? Did you notice that the code is different from the answer you have accepted? Have you yet realised that the answer you have accepted ignores the last entry on each record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PERFORM VARYING MY-SUBSCRIPT FROM +1 BY +1 
        UNTIL MY-SUBSCRIPT NOT LESS THAN NUMBER-IN-FILE-RECORD
    MOVE  IN-FILE-FIELD1(MY-SUBSCRIPT) TO OUT-FILE-FIELD1
     .....
    MOVE  IN-FILE-FIELD99(MY-SUBSCRIPT) TO OUT-FILE-FIELD99
    WRITE OUT-FILE-RECORD
END-PERFORM.
```

Comment: Neal the write MUST be in the loop -- he wants an output record for every set of fields in the OCCURS part of the input record.

Comment: OK, then at least fix the subscripting error: `UNTIL MY-SUBSCRIPT NOT LESS THAN NUMBER-IN-FILE-RECORD` This condition will drop the last table entry. `UNTIL` conditions are evaluated before entering the loop body, you seem to be assuming `TEST AFTER`. The correct condition is: `UNTIL MY-SUBSCRIPT > NUMBER-IN-FILE-RECORD`

Answer (score 3):

In you input-record you will have something like this:

```
01  a-nicely-named-record.
    05  nicely-named-data PIC ...
    ...
    05  and-a-final-nice-name PIC ...
    05  field-containing-the-count-of-actual-entries ... PIC ...
    05  the-COBOL-table.
        10  table-entry OCCURS n TIMES.
            15  table-entry-data-nice-name PIC ...
            ...
            15  table-entry-a-final-nice-name PIC ...
```

Something like that. It is better if you can show your own layout. The `...` means "put here what you actually have, because we don't know the details". You input-record should have a prefix for all the field-names, but may not.

Your output-record:

```
01  a-nicely-named-record.
    05  nicely-named-data PIC ...
    ...
    05  and-a-final-nice-name PIC ...
    05  field-containing-the-count-of-actual-entries ... PIC ...
    05  the-COBOL-table.
        10  table-entry OCCURS n TIMES.
            15  table-entry-data-nice-name PIC ...
            ...
            15  table-entry-a-final-nice-name PIC ...
```

Again, there should be a prefix for all these. But there may not. You say the structure is different, but you haven't shown, so going for "logically" equivalent.

To access a table, you need to use `subscripting`. Subscripting is coded inside `(` and `)`. Subscripting may be with a literal value ( 1 ), ( 2 ) etc, or with an index (defined as `INDEXED BY` on the data definition of the `OCCURS`) or by using a data-name as a subscript.

```
01  the-subscript BINARY PIC 9(4).
```

`BINARY PIC 9(4)` can contain a maximum value of 9999, if your table is bigger (unlikely, but not impossible, for a table on a file) then make it `BINARY PIC 9(8)`.

```
PERFORM
  VARYING the-subscript
    FROM 1
    BY 1
    UNTIL ( the-subscript 
           GREATER THAN field-containing-the-count-of-actual-entries )
    MOVE input-field.... ( the-subscript ) to output-filed... ( the-subscript )
    ...
    MOVE input-field.... ( the-subscript ) to output-filed... ( the-subscript )
END-PERFORM
```

Using an index would be the same as the above, except by referencing the index-name instead of the-subscript.

If the number of entries in your table is small (a relative term) you can just use literals:

```
MOVE input-field.... ( 1 ) TO output-filed... ( 1 )
...
MOVE input-field.... ( 1 ) TO output-filed... ( 1 )
MOVE input-field.... ( n ) TO output-filed... ( n )
...
MOVE input-field.... ( n ) TO output-filed... ( n )
```

If the format of the table is the same on both files and you are sure that the data in the input table conforms exactly to the PICture clauses, it can be done with one MOVE statement.

```
MOVE input-table TO output-table
```

If there are a fixed number of entries on all records, you can use

```
initial value for subscript/index
PERFORM n TIMES
    MOVEs (as above)
    increment subscript/index
END-PERFORM
```

For further clarification if you have problems, update your question with the input and output records, the name of the compiler and the OS that you are using.

Comment: Sometimes people are not interested in a complete or well thought out answer - they just want
a hint to get them on to coding their next bug. The answer they are looking for doesn't have to be complete, or
as you observed, even correct! Sad but true.